# How to get "real" mongo query when running fluent-mongo

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, fluent-mongo

When running my application I have to write to screen raw query used.

Is any method/extension method available, to get from this:

```
IQueryable alldata = hr.GetCollection"EventsReceiver").AsQueryable().Where(q => q.UserId == "123");
```

something similar to:

```
db.EventsReceiver.find({ "userid" : "123" });
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261156/translate-queryablet-back-to-imongoquery?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having same question I'll repost here Craig's answer on github:

```
var queryObject = ((IMongoQueryable)alldata).GetQueryObject();
```

this should give you back the object used to generate the query.

Answer (score 0):

From FluentMongo v1.2.0.0, there's no public way to expose the query (so sad). Here's a dirty extension method to get at it.

BUT since this is using reflection to get at non-public members don't expect that it will necessarily work in the future.

```
public static class MongoQueryableExtensions
{
    public static BsonDocument GetMongoQuery<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        if(query == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("query");
        Assembly fluentMongoAssembly = typeof(FluentMongo.Linq.MongoCollectionExtensions).Assembly;
        Type mongoQueryableType = fluentMongoAssembly.GetType("FluentMongo.Linq.IMongoQueryable");

        BsonDocument queryDocument = null;
        if(mongoQueryableType.IsAssignableFrom(query.GetType()))
        {
            MethodInfo m = mongoQueryableType.GetMethod("GetQueryObject");
            object queryObject = m.Invoke(query, null);

            PropertyInfo queryProperty = fluentMongoAssembly.GetType("FluentMongo.Linq.MongoQueryObject").GetProperty("Query");
            queryDocument = (BsonDocument)queryProperty.GetValue(queryObject, null);
        }
        return queryDocument;
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't this a way? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261156/translate-queryablet-back-to-imongoquery?lq=1