# Translate FilterDefinition<TDocument> to regular json mongo query that i can run in a mongo shell

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have many complex queries that I sometimes wish to check directly against Mongo for debugging \ explaining() purposes. 
With the newer 2.0+ c# driver, i'm not sure how to do this. With the previous version there was a thing called `IMongoQuery` and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261156/translate-queryablet-back-to-imongoquery) worked.

A simple example:

```
FilterDefinition<LalalaEvent> filter = Builders<LalalaEvent>.Filter
    .Where(e => ids.Contains(e.Id) && e.Deleted != true );
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you're using the latest version of the driver, which is 2.0.1 you can easily put that filter in a `Find` operation, get back an `IFindFluent` and print its `ToString`:

```
var filter = Builders<LalalaEvent>.Filter.Where(e => ids.Contains(e.Id) && e.Deleted != true);
var findFluent = collection.Find(filter);
Console.WriteLine(findFluent);
```

For example for me this prints:

```
find({ "_id" : { "$in" : [1, 2, 3] }, "Deleted" : { "$ne" : true } })
```

Answer (score 53):

I was trying to solve the same problem today. Here is what I found.

```
public static class MongoExtensions
{
    public static BsonDocument RenderToBsonDocument<T>(this FilterDefinition<T> filter)
    {
        var serializerRegistry = BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry;
        var documentSerializer = serializerRegistry.GetSerializer<T>();
        return filter.Render(documentSerializer, serializerRegistry);
    }
}
```

I didn't have access to a collection when I was calling it, so I couldn't use the above solutions.

This allows you to do

```
var json = filter.RenderToBsonDocument().ToJson();
```

Comment: Does anyone know how this could be done with IAggregateFluent<T>?

Comment: @Aneef, I think the other answer had already been accepted when I posted my solution.

I appreciate the perpetual stream of upvotes I seem to have gotten for my solution though. haha.

Comment: RenderToBsonDocument throws exception when a field is repeted in the filter, ex: {"myField": { $exists: true }, "myField" : {$ne:""}}

Answer (score 23):

You are able to perform that using the collection's properties:

```
var result = filter.Render(collection.DocumentSerializer,
                           collection.Settings.SerializerRegistry).ToString();
```

Comment: This seems very weird. Why should I need a collection to convert a FilterDefinition to a json string? I see it works, it just doesn't feel like the way one ought to go about it.

Comment: @zrbecker After five years, this is exactly what I was looking for. I already have the collection and wanted see what's going on with the filter. This is a short and neat solution for some cases.